# How can I get recent messages from twitch chat?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get latest messages in twitch chat with python and beautifulsoup, but when I print data it prints empty array.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.twitch.tv/method'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

chat = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "chat-line__message"})

print(chat)
```

> How can I get Twitch chat activity and why is no chat history showing in my request?

Answer (score 0):

The chat data/html won't be on the page when you make the request. This is because the Javascript will go and get the chat activity after you have made the request and update the page. It will continue doing this until you leave the page.

Twitch provides an API you can use to get the chat activity for a channel. 
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/chat